# Is is possible to create a scatter chart in excel that has a 2 dimensional X axis

Tags: excel, tableau-api, powerbi, excel-charts

I'm trying to create what I would call a Vertical stacked scatter plot or a scatte plot with a 2 dimensional x-axis.  I tried using excel's normal charting tools as well as its pivot charting functionality, but I have not been able to crack this one.  As anyone had any luck with this type of a chart or can you recommend a tool that can handle it.   I've included an image of what I'm trying to achieve below:

[image]

The Y axis has months, and the X axis is a combination of Year and Units.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily handled in Tableau, if you and your users have access to it. For example, using sample Excel data with this format:

```
Date       Units
1/1/2014   10
2/1/2014   20
3/1/2014   30
4/1/2014   40
...
```

You can create the scatter plot you've shown in your mock-up by doing the following:

- Drag Date to Rows and change it to Month level
- Drag Date to Columns and leave it at Year level
- Drag Units to Columns
- Change the Marks type to Circle
- Reduce the size of the circles so they look like points
- Sort Month according to your preference

Here's a link to a screenshot of the set-up and resulting plot:

[screenshot of scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd85P.png)

There are also many formatting options to change the look of the plot.